# How to replace part of line in file using sed with regex?

Tags: bash, sed, terminal

I am using sed 
and want to find a part in the file and replace it
I want to find address= and the content inside "" replace 
in this case "my location" replace with London,
I am using the following script which replaces everything that comes after address= while I want to replace only what I have inside ""

```
<test address="my location",it is located>

sed -e s/address =.*$/address =com.test/g /file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is simply:

```
sed -e 's/address=".*"/address="London"/g'
```

The regular expression in your example replaces all characters after `address=` until the end of the line, `$`.

**Edit**: Response to comment:

You could capture `address="` and then refer to it with a backreference, `\1`, in the substitution string:

```
sed -e 's/\(address="\)[^"]*/\1London/g'
```

Comment: Yes ,thanks it is a solution ,but what if I want not to repeat "address"  in the second part, want to search address and after that do the replacement ?

Comment: sed -e "s/\(address="\)[^"]*/\1London/g" \;
I get unbalances brackets ([])